# Reducing the number of brackets in Swift

Tags: swift, shorthand

Does anyone know if there is a way to use some kind shorthand in swift? more specifically, leaving out the braces in things like IF statements... eg

```
if num == 0
  // Do something
```

instead of

```
if num == 0
{
  // Do something
}
```

Those braces become rather space consuming when you have a few nested IF's.

PS. I do know I can do the following:

```
if num == 0 {
  // Do something }
```

But I'm still curious if that sort of thing is possible

Comment: if (!num) // Do something ? - This stack : http://codereview.stackexchange.com Can be better for your question ;)

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work... But even if it did, you're going to have a loooong line if you have 5 nested IF statements :P

Comment: Personally, I recommend sticking to Apple's formatting conventions. If you're having trouble fitting all your code on the screen, buy a bigger screen.

Comment: Or more screens :D @MattGibson

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can do that :

```
let x = 10, y = 20;
let max = (x < y) ? y : x ; // So max = 20
```

And so much interesting things :

```
let max = (x < y) ? "y is greater than x" : "x is greater than y" // max = "y is greater than x"
let max = (x < y) ? true : false // max = true
let max = (x > y) ? func() : anotherFunc() // max = anotherFunc()
(x < y) ? func() : anotherFunc() // code is running func()
```

This following stack : http://codereview.stackexchange.com can be better for your question ;)

**Edit : ternary operators and compilation**

> By doing nothing more than replacing the ternary operator with an if else statement, the build time was reduced by 92.9%.

https://medium.com/@RobertGummesson/regarding-swift-build-time-optimizations-fc92cdd91e31#.42uncapwc

Comment: I'll have a look there, thanks. That code doesnt seem to work by the way... Says a brace needs to follow the IF

Comment: It won't work. You have to have braces in swift for if statement.

Comment: The code doesn't work because it uses 'int' where it should use 'let'. Do 'let x = 10, y = 20; let max = (x < y) ? y : x'

Comment: Your example is correct but to get the max of two values you can use `let maxValue = max(x, y)` The max function will return the maximum value. So, don't use it to get the max value of two integers

Answer (score 4):

In swift you have to add braces even if there is just one statement in if:

```
if num == 0 {
  // Do something
}
```

You cannot leave the braces, that how swift if statement work.

Comment: Swift is designed to be safer than C — requiring braces for `if` statements helps keep you from writing bugs like the infamous `goto fail`. As noted in other answers, you're welcome to use the ternary operator `? :` just like in C if you want to be terse (or do things like conditional assignment to a `let`).

Answer (score 4):

You could use a shorthand if statement like you would in objective-c:

```
num1 < num2 ? DO SOMETHING IF TRUE : DO SOMETHING IF FALSE
```

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 2.0 update**
Method 1:

```
a != nil ? a! : b
```

Method 2: Shorthand if

```
b = a ?? ""
```

Referance: [Apple Docs: Ternary Conditional Operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID71)

and it does work,

```
u.dob = (userInfo["dob"] as? String) != nil ? (userInfo["dob"] as! String):""
```

I am replacing a json string with blank string if it is nil.

Edit: Adding  **Gerardo Medina`s** suggestion...we can always use shorthand If

```
u.dob = userInfo["dob"] as? String ?? ""
```

Comment: you can do it easier in this way:
a ?? b,   
u.dob = (userInfo["dob"] as? String) ?? ""

Answer (score 1):

It is called shorthand if-else condition. If you are into iOS development in Swift, then you can also manipulate your UI objects' behaviour with this property.

For e.g. - I want my button to be enabled only when there is some text in the textfield. In other words, should stay disabled when character count in textfield is zero.

`button.enabled = (textField.characters.count > 0) ? true : false`

Answer (score 1):

its very simple :
in Swift 4

```
    playButton.currentTitle == "Play" ? startPlay() : stopPlay()
```

Original Code is

```
    if playButton.currentTitle == "Play"{
     StartPlay()
    }else{
     StopPlay()
    }
```

Comment: Thanks... Same as the answer given in 2014 though... :)

Comment: ha ha ,,,but in 2014 swift 4 is not published :)

Answer (score 0):

You could always put the entire `if` on one line:

```
if num == 0 { temp = 0 }
```