# Are all brackets for if-statements and loops in Swift optional?

Tags: swift, if-statement, for-loop, brackets

I'm new to swift and heard that you may put brackets but you don't have to use them in if-statements and loops.

```
for eachView in allSubViews {
    if (eachView is UILabel) {
        // code
    }
}
```

If i put brackets around the "eachView in allSubViews", my Xcode complains about it and i have to remove them :O
Why?
in the if-statement, it's ok with or without brackets.

Comment: Maybe you should post the actual code.

Comment: Take a look ate [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24507072/reducing-the-number-of-brackets-in-swift)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the language syntax, the `if` statement is defined like this:

```
if *expression* {
```

and you can always add parenthesis around expressions.

However, `for-in` is defined as:

```
for *item* in *collection expression* {
```

You can still add parenthesis around the expression. However, you cannot put parenthesis around the keyword `in`.

Comment: You can't put parenthesis around `if let` statements.